# How can i make a booststraps rows clickabel and open a modal using the same row id

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can i make a booststraps rows clickabel and open a modal using the same row id, the table info is
coming from a database. using ajax

```
$(function (){

 $('#realizePay').modal({
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: "static",
    show: false,

}).on('show', function () {
});

$(".loan_table").find('td').on('click', function () {
    debugger;

    $('#idPay').html($('<input type="text" id="idread" name="" class="form-control">'));
    $('#realizePay').modal('show');
});});
```

Comment: Hello Kenmir, I can see you are a new member. Kindly post your code and your current progress so that stack overflow community can help you better. No one can explain you complete code here, without looking at something for starters. So kindly post the relevant issue with code snippets or images or any supporting material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code might work. Here I have updated, check this once.

```js
(function (){

 $('#realizePay').modal({
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: "static",
    show: false,
}).on('show', function () {
    // your ajax call or whatever actions you want on modal show.
});

$(document).on('click', ".loan_table tr", function () {
    debugger;

    $('#idPay').html($('<input type="text" id="idread" name="" class="form-control">'));
    $('#realizePay').modal('show');
});
});
```